# What is this construct in bash? mycommand(){dosomething;}

Tags: command-line, bash

I actually found following one-liner on commandfu.com:

`cmdfu(){ curl "http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/matching/$@/$(echo -n $@ | openssl base64)/plaintext"; }`
I have not come across a similar use of the `()` in bash before.

It seems that it creates the command  `cmdfu` temporarily within the bash environment. Am I correct here? Or is it actually stored somewhere?
Is there a name for this construct so I can read up on it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a shell function. If you create it at the command line, it will exist only for the current shell invocation. You can add the definition to a shell startup file (.bashrc, .bash_profile, etc) and it will make it "permanent".

If you search the `bash(1)` manpage for "Shell Function Definitions" you can see the syntax for defining shell functions. The section "FUNCTIONS" goes into more details of functions themselves.

Comment: You can also use functions inside scripts to organize and reuse code in the same way you'd use them in other languages.